# htmlspecialchars won't convert quotes

Tags: php, html

htmlspecialchars won't work in my page to remove the back slashes before escaped apostrophes placed there by pdo objects.  I am assuming this is because I am using UTF-8 on my page to display Chinese characters.  I am trying to display a paragraph in English and a paragraph in Chinese.  This is the code I am using:

```
$english=htmlspecialchars($row["english"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

For some reason it always displays like this:

```
Don\'t
```

There is no removal of the escape character...

Comment: Why do you think [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) *should* be stripping slashes? (And why are you storing slashes like that in your database?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. PDO objects do not place slashes for `'`.
2. `htmlspecialchars()` do not strip slashes
3. It is actually incorrect to escape single quotes during display in HTML, only double quotes are special symbols.

So, here is usual example of XY problem (can I show this question to students?)

To understand what is going wrong you need to know next things:

1. PHP can add `\` to input arguments if [magic_quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) are enabled - you need to turn them off (via php.ini or during [runtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) for php < 5.3. Also turn off [magic_quotes_sybase](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sybase.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-sybase).
2. During insertion of data into database you (sometimes) need to escape single-quotes. This is usually done by PDO functions *if you're using them right*. If you're using [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), you do not need to use any other escaping.
3. During fetching of data from database you may have problems with [magic_quotes_runtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime), so turn them off.
4. Finally, you're outputting your data to HTML -- here you need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) but without any attributes, as the default ones are okay.

If you have 1 or 2 problem - data in your database may already be corrupt, so you need to re-save them without the incorrectly added `\` - for this you can use [`stripslashes()`](https://www.php.net/stripslashes), but only one time to re-save data. During ordinary work of your system, you need to use proper approach.

Comment: I had magic_quotes_gpc=On in the .ini file which apparently adds the back slashes when using a post.  By using bindParam from the post data, will this be a sufficient layer of security against sql injection once the magic_quotes_gpc is off?

Comment: @trueinViso yes, bindParam is enough to avoid sql injection problems, just use it for all queries and for all variables, magic_quotes were "invented" before PDO came and this is why now php has problems if both are used

Answer (score 2):

> Don\'t

This shouldn't be happening in the first place. There is likely a bug further up the stream (like, when the data gets inserted into the database) that should be fixed, instead of treating the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

replace your variable with this:

```
$english = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($row["english"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

the stripslashes part will get rid of the slashes, but it might un-sanitize your string.